# Delphi CrossTalk and C# Public Static classes

Tags: c#, delphi

I'm trying to use Delphi and CrossTalk in conjunction with a C# set of Class libraries.

I'm getting an error message as per:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I can't seem to get around this ..

Note the public static type of class definition and instantiation "on the fly".

Code in class `class RESTAdapterConfig` is for reading a section of content out of a .config file.

I can use the classes fine with an "all C#" application approach.
The class I'm having an issue with is as per:

```cs
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;

namespace HHHHHH.Adapters
{
    public class RESTAdapterConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        public static RESTAdapterConfig Instance { get; private set; }
        private static object instanceLock = new object();

        static RESTAdapterConfig()
        {
            if (Instance == null)
                lock (instanceLock)
                    if (Instance == null)
                        Instance = (RESTAdapterConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RESTAdapterConfig");
        }

        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(HttpHeaders), AddItemName = "httpHeader")]
        public class HttpHeaders : ConfigurationElementCollection
        {
            protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
            {
                return new HttpHeader();
            }

            protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
            {
                if (element == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("httpHeader");

                return ((HttpHeader)element).Key;
            }

            public new HttpHeader this[string key]
            {
                get { return (HttpHeader)base.BaseGet(key); }
            }
        }
```

Also a RestAdapter.cs class contains

```cs
private static dynamic Submit(RESTRequest request, AuthType authType, object requestBody)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = GetWebRequest(request, authType);
{etc}

private static HttpWebRequest GetWebRequest(RESTRequest request, AuthType authType)
{
    var uri = new Uri(GetServiceUrl(request));
{etc}

private static string GetServiceUrl(RESTRequest request)
{
    var baseURL = RESTAdapterConfig.Instance.baseURL.URL;
```

The Delphi code is as per:

```pascal
var
    ARESTAdapter: RESTAdapter;
    GenerateHRF605StatusRequest: RESTRequest;
    //ARESTAdapterConfig : RESTAdapterConfig;
    HRF605Req: HRF605Request;
    PartialURL: string;
begin

    // Call Web service

    try
        ARESTAdapter := RESTAdapter.Create;
        try
            PartialURL := 'generateHRF605';
            GenerateHRF605StatusRequest := RESTRequest.Create;
            GenerateHRF605StatusRequest.PartyCode := DataModule.AJF2GetPartyId;
            GenerateHRF605StatusRequest.Method := 'POST';
            GenerateHRF605StatusRequest.ApiVersion := 1;
            GenerateHRF605StatusRequest.Path := PartialURL;
            HRF605Req := HRF605Request.Create(
                            FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', rsRangeSelector.DateFrom) ,
                            FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', rsRangeSelector.DateTo) ,
                                                        0,
                            '\\FILESERVER01\H2FileRepository\Dev\CommonDev\reports\');
            //HRF605Req := HRF605Request.Create;
            //HRF605Req.FromDate := FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', rsRangeSelector.DateFrom) ;
            //HRF605Req.ToDate := FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', rsRangeSelector.DateTo);
            //HRF605Req.MembershipId := 100;
            //HRF605Req.MembershipId := 100;
            //HRF605Req.FolderPath := null;
            //ShowMessage('Debug:  FromDate: ' +  HRF605Req.FromDate + ' ToDate: ' +  HRF605Req.ToDate + ' PartyID : ' + GenerateHRF605StatusRequest.PartyCode) ;

            try
                ARESTAdapter.HRF605RequestHelloWorld();
                //have tried both
                //ARESTAdapter.SubmitHRF605Request(GenerateHRF605StatusRequest,HRF605Req);
                ARESTAdapter.SubmitHRF605Request(GenerateHRF605StatusRequest,HRF605Req);

            finally
                HRF605Req.Free;
                GenerateHRF605StatusRequest.Free;
            end;
        finally
            ARESTAdapter.Free;
        end;
    except on E: Exception do
        raise EhslException.Create(StringReplace(E.Message, 'RESTException: ', '', [rfIgnoreCase]));
    end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I had correct sections in the correct .config file I managed to get this to work.

The correct config file is the one that matches your .exe file.

e.g. if running ABC.exe then config is looked for in ABC.exe.config.

I also had to declare the sections in the top of the config file in the  area .. in addition to having the config sections in the configuration just above last  tag.

Use of the Visual Studio "Immediate window" helps debug also.
e.g. looking at the value of expression;
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RESTAdapterConfig")

Another tip for debugging to run the Delphi app as a standalone exe but then once it is running use Attach to Process in Visual Studio to connect to your Delphi exe and then put a breakpoint on the code you expect to hit in the adapter / dll 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019

Another developer suggested change to use code pattern of "static instance (singleton)" which I did as per here .. (but prev code as per question would have worked also given correct config in correct file.)

```
public class RESTAdapterConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
    private static readonly RESTAdapterConfig instance = (RESTAdapterConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("RESTAdapterConfig");
    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    // The laziness of type initializers is only guaranteed by .NET when the type isn't marked with a special flag called beforefieldinit.
    // The C# compiler marks all types which don't have a static constructor (i.e. a block which looks like a constructor but is marked static) as beforefieldinit.
    static RESTAdapterConfig()
    {
    }

    public static RESTAdapterConfig Instance { get { return instance; } }
```